# Variable bounding reset

Tags: python, loops, variables, while-loop

So learning to code...Can someone explain why the count resets to 0 with every loop? Does this happen with all loops, when you exit all data resets? If so is there a rule of thumb to follow that can help you figure out when the bounding on a variable changes in or stays the same(in a loop or out of a loop?

```
iteration = 0
while iteration < 5:
    count = 0
    for letter in "hello, world":
        count += 1
    print "Iteration " + str(iteration) + "; count is: " + str(count)
    iteration += 1
```

Comment: You should indicate what you were expecting as output.

Comment: I was expecting an outcome of 60 for count.

Answer (score 1):

on every loop you're reassigning `count` to `0`you have to put count out of the loop

your code should be like this

```
iteration = 0
count = 0
while iteration < 5:
    for letter in "hello, world":
        count += 1
    print "Iteration " + str(iteration) + "; count is: " + str(count)
    iteration += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The `count` resets to 0 each time through the loop because the statement that sets it to zero is *inside* the loop. Move it up before the `while` and change the indentation, and you'll be fine.

Comment: This is my question exactly, does everything inside a loop basically reset to whatever you set it to?

Comment: @MJ49 it all happens in sequence. When you start over at the top of the loop, all the statements in the loop are executed in turn. If one of those statements sets a variable to a specific value, then that's what it will be as the execution moves forward.

Answer (score 0):

The count is resetting to `0` on every loop because, on the first line after your `while`, you assign zero to it: `count = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no separate scope (or namespace) for while loops, elements defined inside it do not get lost when the scope of the while loop ends. Example to show this -

```
>>> i
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
>>> x = 0
>>> while  x < 5:
...     x += 1
...     i = 12
...
>>> i
12
```

In your code, you are the one who is resetting count at the start of each iteration with the line -

```
count = 0
```

If you do not want to reset count, then you should move that line to before the while loop.

---

Even with `for` loop , its the same. Also , please note even the counter variable in for loop is created in the surrounding namespace/scope. Example -

```
>>> y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
>>> for y in range(10):
...     pass
...
>>> y
9
```